# Setting the buffer size when reading a Stream in WCF and writing it to a Microsoft SQL Server database table

Tags: c#, wcf, filestream, nettcpbinding, sqlclient

When receiving a `Stream` in `WCF` and writing it to a database table, what buffer size is used when writing the data to the database table and how can it be changed?

I'm using .NET Framework 4.6 and Microsoft SQL Server.

**Server**

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "IUploadFileService")]
public interface IUploadFileService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void UploadFile(UploadFileMessage uploadFileMessage);
}

[MessageContract]
public class UploadFileMessage
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream FileContents { get; set; }
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class UploadFileService : IUploadFileService
{
    public void UploadFile(UploadFileMessage uploadFileMessage)
    {
        using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            DbConnection conn = context.Database.Connection;
            ConnectionState initialState = conn.State;

            try
            {
                if (initialState != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }

                using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    // the FileContents field is a `varbinary(max)` data type
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Files] (FileContents) VALUES (@FileContents)";
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

                    DbParameter parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
                    parameter.ParameterName = "@FileContents";
                    parameter.DbType = DbType.Binary;
                    parameter.Size = -1;
                    parameter.Value = uploadFileMessage.FileContents; // what buffer size is used to read this Stream and write it to the database?
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (initialState != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Server configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IFileUploadService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="32505856" maxStringContentLength="32505856" />
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
                <message clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Client**

```
private static void UploadFile()
{
     EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:4502/FileUploadService");

     NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None)
     {
         TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
         MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
         MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
         SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue
     };

     FileUploadServiceClient fileUploadServiceClient = new FileUploadServiceClient(binding, endpointAddress);

     using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\test.bin", FileMode.Open)) // read buffer size is 4096 bytes by default
     {
         fileUploadServiceClient.UploadFile(fileStream);
     }
}
```

Is it any of these?

- Default value specified in `FileStream` used to open the file on the client
- `NetTcpBinding.MaxBufferSize` on the client
- `maxBufferSize` in the WCF server configuration
- `DbParameter.Size`, which is `int.MaxValue` because it's set to `-1` and the maximum number of bytes that can be entered in a `varbinary(max)` database field
- `Network Packet Size` configuration setting in the SQL Server database
- `MTU` values on the network
- Smallest value of all of the above

Thank you.

Comment: "*what buffer size is used when writing the data to the database*" this question seemingly is specific, but in actuality is very ambiguous. So are you talking about the size of network packets used to communicate with an instance of SQL Server?

Comment: @TheGeneral, I added a comment next to the specific line in question `parameter.Value = uploadFileMessage.FileContents; // what buffer size is used to read this Stream and write it to the database?` It's the only place where the `Stream` is passed to the `ADO.NET` layer. I'm wondering which buffer size `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` is using here and how I can set its value to align with the other buffer sizes involved, including the SQL Servers network packet size. I'm also really only interested in being able to programmatically set it's value if it's part of the application layer. Thank you.

Comment: There is no difference in writing binary data to a database than a string.  You can't add add character to a string in a database.  You replace the entire string.  So it is no different with bytes than strings.

Comment: @jdweng, SqlClient handles `Stream`s differently when compared to a byte array or string because the data in a byte array and string are already loaded in memory. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support I'm wondering if I can control the number of bytes loaded in memory at a given time (buffer size) of the `Stream` and how. Thank you.

Comment: Lets take a step back for a moment and try to understand what you are trying to do.  It appears you are trying to upload a binary file to a server.  So with uploading binary data the receive end needs to know where the end of the data occurs.  So normally you add a byte count to beginning of upload.  So the question is how do you know how much data you are gong to upload if you do not read the size of the data from the SQL Server?

Comment: @jdweng, the code on the client uses a `FileStream` to read data. By default, it reads the file using a buffer size of 4096 bytes. If that's the answer, how can I measure it on the server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) transports support two modes for transferring messages:

1.Buffered transfers hold the entire message in a memory buffer until the transfer is complete. A buffered message must be completely delivered before a receiver can read it.

2.Streamed transfers expose the message as a stream. The receiver starts processing the message before it is completely delivered.

I see that you use the second transfer mode, streaming, which can improve the scalability of services by eliminating the need for large memory buffers.

To prevent denial of service attacks, WCF exposes a MaxReceivedMessageSize attribute to limit the size attribute of incoming messages, so it also limits the maximum amount of memory accessed when processing the message. The unit is set in bytes, and the default value is 65,536 bytes.

For more information about Streaming Message Transfer,Please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/streaming-message-transfer